# How can I pass React props in audio player?

Tags: reactjs, audio, next.js, jsx, react-props

I created a **component** for an audio player and I'm trying make the **src** editable in different files  `<audio controls src={sourceFile}/>`.
I tried to use react props but it isn't working how can I fix this?

**I am using Next.js**

Component file:

```
    const AudioPlayer = (sourceFile) => {
      return (
     <div>
        <audio preload="metadata" controls src={sourceFile} />
      </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default AudioPlayer;
```

index.js

```
<AudioPlayer sourceFile="audio.mp3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your const function parameter so it knows its looking for props

```
const AudioPlayer = ({sourceFile}) => {...
```